# trace part of an image, extrude into 3d object?

Tags: image, extrude

I have a logo it's an image of earth and around it are arrows, I would like to trace a plane along those arrows please
[image]

if there's any special instructions to extruding it please let me know

Comment: please explain more in details, show some pictures, screenshots, etc...

Comment: oh sorry, I'm trying to take this image and turn the arrows to the left of the earth into 3d objects https://imgur.com/a/mh2Xntc ---- I guess I gotta load the image in blender, and trace the arrows maybe somehow then just extrude them straight upwards a little to make them 3d? ---- I can do this with text already for example, type some text, change it to mesh, then extrude it upwards so it's 3d, I'm looking to do that but with the arrows on that image, so I guess I gotta know if I can just trace them free hand or something?

Comment: @bacobaco you can use the [edit] link at the bottom of your post (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) to include pertinent information as part of the question.